# XPS L501X Very Slow, Lags and Freezes

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, hardware-failure, lag

I have a major lagging problem with my XPS L501x. It lags in everything: browsing, gaming, opening files, Ctrl+F in txt files takes too long to open, even the right click lags, watching youtube videos, games, programs, applying settings on anything, playing music and video files, switching between tabs in any browser, opening folders, typing, etc..

I formatted all the hard drive including all partitions and done a clean Windows 7 Home Premium 64-Bit Installation, updated all the drivers definitions but problem wasn't resolved. I ran dell diagnostics by pressing the F12 key while starting up and it passed all the tests, updated the BIOS to A08. Also cleaned all vents to remove dust and used a cooling pad under the laptop but the problem still exists.

I uninstalled the Intel Rapid Storage Driver as I found that this may help but with no luck too.

I ran a memtest to check the laptop memory and no errors are found. then I ran a hard disk diagnostics tool (HD Tune Pro.) which came up with some errors and I don't know whether this errors are the cause of lags or not.

It came up with 31 damaged sectors and 104402084 interface CRC error count and I actually don't know what does this error means. I also was monitoring the temperature and it varies between 50 to 52 C, I don't know whether it is normal or not. Last thing I noticed the read access time is 18.9 ms which is yellow highlighted by the software so maybe it is abnormal. I want to know if my hard drive working normal or this results shows a hard disk failure and needs replace? and If I replaced it this will solve the slow/lags problem or not?

Note: Processor temperature on load: 70 to 73c maximum. Intel Core i7 740QM 1.73GHZ.

Any suggestions please?

My Laptop Specs:

Intel Core i7 1.73 GHz with TurboBoost

RAM: 6GB

Nvidia GeForce GT 435M 2GB Dedicated.

Toshiba Hard Disk: 640GB

Comment: Hard to say, but I'd bet it's the HDD, especially if everything else is checking out. HDDs go out all the time. Its worth a shot, a system with those specs shouldn't be running slow.

Comment: @MDTGuy Thank you for your reply I really appreciate it. I will try to replace my dell hard disk with my hp pavilion hard disk and see if the problem with the hard or another hardware but I need to know first if this can be done without losing data or not. I posted a new question and I'd be very thankful if you took a look on it. Thank you again. http://superuser.com/questions/677660/replacing-laptop-hard-drive