# Replacing laptop hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, laptop, dell-xps

I have two laptops, a Dell XPS running 64-bit and HP Pavilion 32-bit and I want to replace the Dell hard drive with the hard drive in the HP temporarily because my Dell laptop became very slow and I want to test if the problem is with the hard drive or something else. The question is: Can I do that without losing data in the two hard drives? I know that maybe data on C partitions will be deleted and that's OK, but will the rest of the data will be lost or not?

Comment: It depends on your plan of the entire action. What exactly are you going to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm just gonna take the hp hard disk and put in the dell to see if the dell laptop works fine with this hard disk or not. If it worked fine then the problem will be in the dell hard disk causing it slower and lags and I will replace it with a new one. @gronostaj

Comment: It won't boot. Windows installations are configured for the hardware they are installed on. You can try plugging it as a secondary drive instead of optical drive, but this way you won't be able to test it reliably.

Comment: Unless you plan to reinstall the OS, data should be safe. However, I am skeptical about OS itself. If its OEM copy, it may not work on laptop of other brand..

Comment: Replacing the HD just because the OS is slow might not be the best solution. Perhaps your OS (in the Dell) is slow for a reason other than the HD. (For instance if your %temp% directory is too big, Virusscanner is in the way, etc...) If you're planning to clone the HD you might up with the same slowness and if you re-install the OS on a new HD you'll never know for sure what caused the slowness. Did you do a HD check (in case you HD is defective)? Did you run CCleaner (in case your OS is messy)?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, maybe you are right at this point. I just tested the HDD with HD tune  pro and it came up with 31 damaged sectors and 104402084 interface CRC error count. Does this indicates a hard disk failure?

Comment: Backup... backup fast.... it might be ok but damaged sectors ussually mean a failing hd. If they get worse get a new one.

Comment: @tumchaaditya I have a bootable disk for windows 7 home premium 64-bit and another one 32-bit.

Comment: @Rik Thank you for your replies I really appreciate it. I will backup my valuable data now. Dell diagnostics didn't show any errors on the hard disk however, the HD tune pro shows those 31 damaged sectors and the interface CRC error count. My laptop lags in everything even while listening to music or watching videos it just freezes for a couple of seconds as if it paused and then continues. Do you advice to replace the hard disk or what? Thank you again.

Comment: Lagging is a typical symptom of dying hard drive. Appearance of bad sectors usually means the drive will die soon. With that many bad sectors you should consider that drive a ticking timebomb. As @Rik said, you should start doing backups right now. Keep drive usage to minimum to avoid wearing it further.

Comment: From what you've described, there's no way of knowing if the issue is the disk or the controller . . . your plan of using another disk to isolate isn't bad, but you likely won't be able to boot off a different systems hard drive . . . you'll most likely need a third hard drive to test with . . .

Comment: @gronostaj Thank you very much. I'm doing the backup now and probably will replace the hard disk with new one.

Comment: @ernie Thanks for your reply, The 31 damaged sectors indicates a dying HDD. Does the 104402084 interface CRC error count indicates a bad controller?

Comment: And after making the backup you can test the HD to your hearts desire. If HD Tune comes back with a higher number than before the drive is probably failing and needs to be replaced. (Or if somebody has better idea at least you have the backup) You could for instance reformat the hd but if the bad sectors stay i wouldn't trust it anymore.

Comment: I formatted all the HDD two times before. Still lags and when I started the HD tune software it came up with the errors mentioned above. What do you suggest? Thank you again. @Rik

Comment: (After backup) you could do a complete surface scan. If after that the damaged sectors increased... toss the HD and get a new one. Increasing number of bad sectors almost always mean a failing drive. If they stay the same... then i don't know... You could use it but if it keeps lagging maybe it's still a physical problem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions @Rik .. I'll rescan it again and probably will replace the HDD with a new one. If you have any other suggestions please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: I got these errors from HDDScan 3.3 software. It shows a S.M.A.R.T Report. Here is a screenshot http://oi40.tinypic.com/20qlwm1.jpg @Rik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved . It was the hard drive, it has delay. Dell diagnostics didn't show the hard drive delay. A technician have made a delay test with a software and it came up with a delay error in the hard drive. Software called HDD Regenerator.

I replaced it with a new one and the problem totally solved. No lags or freezing anymore. I just wanted to share my experience if anyone have this problem, this post may help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you plug the disk to the other laptop externally and try to copy files to and from it. To see the speed of copy operation. This will not harm your disks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Actually while copying files to USB flash drive the laptop becomes more slower and I can barely use it for listening music, watching video, browsing etc.. It delays responding in anything and freezes for a couple of seconds. I got copy transfer speed 17.5 Mbps to 21.5 Mbps using USB 3.0 port to transfer 5.43 GB of 36 video files

Answer (score 2):

There's a far easier way to get better information about the health of your hard drive.

Download HD tune, check the SMART status, run speed tests and post here if you don't understand the results. 
www.hdtune.com

Comment: Thank you for your reply, This is what I actually have done. I tested the HDD with HD tune pro and it came up with 31 damaged sectors, 104402084 interface CRC error count and 18.9 ms access read time which is yellow highlighted by the software so it probably maybe abnormal. Does this indicates a hard disk failure?

Comment: Reallocated sector count? 31 bad sectors isn't a great start. You've got backups of anything important right?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing backups for my valuable data now. What about the Interface CRC error count? Thank you again.

Comment: Interface crc concerns the SATA interface. While the number is high, it's the bad/reallocated sector counts that you should be most concerned with. Tbh My guess is yes,  you need a new drive.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I decided to buy a new hard drive hope to solve the problem. If you have any other suggestions please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: I got these errors from HDDScan 3.3 software. It shows a S.M.A.R.T Report. Here is a screenshot http://oi40.tinypic.com/20qlwm1.jpg

Comment: Yep, get a new hard drive. Your laptop is slow because every time it searches the HDD for anything the head is getting redirected all over the place by the reallocated sectors.